# Double ask for password and thus I can't use sshpass

Tags: ssh, svn, password

The following command asks `Password:` twice. It would be acceptable but I can't use sshpass to automate it :-(

```
$ svn checkout svn+ssh://svn@svn.logostudio.co.il/home/svn/repos/logostudio/trunk/logo/
```

What to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016542/why-svn-asks-my-password-twice

Answer (score 1):

From [Version control with subversion](http://books.google.be/books?id=b3TsOSvU5TUC&lpg=PA204&ots=zTFC7-8cvB&dq=When%20using%20svn%2bssh://%20URLs%20to%20access%20a%20repository,%20remember%20that%20it%27s%20the%20ssh%20program%20prompting%20for%20authentication,%20and%20not%20the%20svn%20client%20program.%20Th&hl=nl&pg=PA204#v=onepage&q=When%20using%20svn%20ssh://%20URLs%20to%20access%20a%20repository,%20remember%20that%20it%27s%20the%20ssh%20program%20prompting%20for%20authentication,%20and%20not%20the%20svn%20client%20program.%20Th&f=false):

> When using svn+ssh:// URLs to access a repository, remember that it's the ssh program prompting for authentication, and not the svn client program. That means there's no automatic password-caching going on (see the section called "Client Credentials Caching"). The Subversion client often makes multiple connections to the repository, though users don't normally notice this due to the password caching feature. When using svn+ssh:// URLs, however, users may be annoyed by ssh repeatedly asking for a password for every outbound connection. The solution is to use a separate SSH password-caching tool such as ssh-agent on a Unix-like system, or pageant on Windows.